# Facebook IN clause in FQL query

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I have a big problem with Facebook FQL, if i do

```
select message from stream where source_id=175102475936031
```

I can get the correct data, if i do this

```
select message from stream where source_id IN(175102475936031,etc,etc,etc)
```

I got a empty JSON, why? is there any alternative to this select? I have to read the messages from multiple events.

Comment: you can always try to write source_id = ID OR source_id = ID2 OR .. , after all it is the same but ugly :) You will get at least idea if this is allowed

Comment: good idea, but unfortunately does not work .. I do not get any results

Comment: strange - what I would do is to make two seaprate queries for two different ID to ensure that they both return something and then try to write a query with one OR - if this will not work it could mean that you cannot do this - however I admit it would be strange

Comment: do different queries is not efficient and makes the site too slow

Comment: I start to think that I can't do this.. but i can't find in the documentation where it says

Comment: according to this presentation http://www.slideshare.net/csaila/fql-overview (slide 27) you can do IN.

Comment: thanks for this presentation, but the problem is ever the same

Comment: Same problem.. Random users cannot be found with the in clause while visible for the '=' clause.. any fixes / bug reports?

Answer (score 2):

Is your problem solved?

"IN" query is a supported feature of FQL. I have tried it multiple times. 
Only needs to have:

1. column indexable
2. needs to have permission to access data
3. data should be present for at least one column :P

   select message from stream where source_id IN( 175102475936031, etc, etc, etc)

"NOT IN" is not a supported feature of FQL. Ref: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=1420

Comment: can't get this to work. Are you sure the statement (still) works in 2013 ?